# Can async subscriber example lose messages?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

Starting off with pubsub. When reading the google cloud documentation, i ran into a snippet of code, and i think i see a flaw with the example.

This is the code i am talking about. It uses the async subscriber.

```java
public class SubscriberExample {

  private static final String PROJECT_ID = ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId();

  private static final BlockingQueue<PubsubMessage> messages = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();

  static class MessageReceiverExample implements MessageReceiver {

    @Override
    public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {
      messages.offer(message);
      consumer.ack();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    String subscriptionId = args[0];
    ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(
        PROJECT_ID, subscriptionId);
    Subscriber subscriber = null;
    try {
      subscriber =
          Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, new MessageReceiverExample()).build();
      subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
      while (true) {
        PubsubMessage message = messages.take();
        processMessage(message);
      }
    } finally {
      if (subscriber != null) {
        subscriber.stopAsync();
      }
    }
  }
```

My question is, what if a bunch of messages have been acknowledged, and the BlockingQueue is not empty, and the server crashes. Then i would lose some messages right? (Acknowledged in PubSub, but not actually processed).

Wouldn't the best implementation be to only acknowledge the message after the it has been processed? Instead of acknowledging it and leaving it on a queue, and assuming it will be processed. I understand this will decouple the receiving of messages and process of messages, and potentially increase throughput, but still it risks losing messages right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one should not acknowledge a message until it has been fully processed. Otherwise, the message may never be processed because it will not be redelivered in the event of a crash or restart if it was acknowledged. I have [entered an issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/issues/1531) to update the example.